# fullpage.js active state on duplicate menu's

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

Working with fullpage.js I have a menu in de header. Setup as in doc. Working fine. When I go on small screens I hide de menu with css. With css I pu a menubutton triggering a js dropdown. In the dropdown I have the same code for menu as in the desktop header. Everything works fine, but I can't get the active state to work in that menu.

Can I get the same menu working on two places on a site (when you hide one, its still in the code) or do I have to remove the div with js?

**URL**

development.darktown.ch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following [the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) regarding how to use the `menu` option.
You have:

```
menu: ['#menu','#m-menu'],
```

And the documentation states:

> **menu**: (default false) **A selector** can be used to specify the menu to link with the sections.

Yours is not a selector but an array of selectors.

Just use a class instead:

```
menu: '.menu'
```

And use a class in both elements instead of an id. (or additionally to it)

Comment: an adition question. Can I make it hear or should I make a new one?